# Is it okay to ask the same question in two different programming languages?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

I have asked a question, entitled [C, exit and pcntl_wait functions produce multiples of 256, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116238/c-exit-and-pcntl-wait-functions-produce-multiples-of-256-why), under the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) tag that is not getting many views and is very likely not to be answered.

The same problem can be reproduced in [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c). Is it okay to ask the same question under the `C` tag? Or should I delete the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) question first?

Comment: Valid in both PHP *and* C? Is it about floating-point?

Comment: Its an OS thing, not really a C or PHP thing (just looked at his question).

Comment: As a C question, it is a duplicate.

Comment: It really depends on the question. If you are asking how to inherit from multiple classes, you would have to specify that you are asking for C++ as opposed to C#, which have different mechanisms (and even philosophies) for doing such a thing. If the mechanics for the languages are so obviously different that there really is no line-for-line analog code between the two, then ask different questions. In your particular case, psuedocode would be fine, or just add a C tag and specify that answers in C will do as the translation is exact.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After looking at your question, I would edit to tag both languages. I say this because you have a special case, you are calling the same OS function from both languages and wondering about its return value.

Make sure to include the code in both languages that reproduces the problem.

I can't think of any case where you should self-duplicate. Also be *very* clear why you are tagging both languages, as people get (understandably) annoyed when a question is tagged [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)

Comment: Sounds good, thanks for the advice, I have taken it to heart and asked the question accordingly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116238/c-exit-and-pcntl-wait-functions-produce-multiples-of-256-why

Comment: I agree. When I can, I make the effort to point out that I tagged two languages because I know the concept applies to both. I think it's best to do it that way, as two problems could be solved almost identically with minor syntax differences in languages like java and C#.

Comment: @McAdam331 I'd be careful about those two tags, the runtimes are different, even though the syntax is similar. Also, you probably are only interested in *one* of the solutions. Not saying don't ever do it, just make sure you *should* be doing it.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET you're right. You inspired me to go back and look at my question of java and C# together and I realized it really had nothing to do with Java. It was an OOP concept, but I was trying to accomplish it in C#. Hopefully the question is of a little better quality now.

Comment: Maybe it should be tagged under neither of these languages if the problem happens in Python, Java, [insert any other language] as well.

Answer (score 13):

Do not ask a question under more than one language if answers that exclusively apply to only one of those languages are unacceptable.

Also, do not ask a question under a language if the question has absolutely nothing to do with the language at all, as in this case. Your question has nothing to do with PHP or C, the same issue can be reproduced in any language with a C FFI- so basically, all of them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have taken down the PHP one and put up the C question

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with you on not tagging the language. What *would* you tag it with? Presumably language experts using that function know the answer.

Comment: The fact that they are language experts is irrelevant. They know the answer only because of use of that specific function, which is language-independent. The function is provided by the OS, so it should be tagged with that OS and only that. If you are an expert in the PHP language, that means absolutely nothing about whether or not you can answer the question, which is an instant hint that tagging PHP is dumb.

Comment: I would argue that whether or not a function is language independent is more an implementation detail of the function. From the asker's perspective, it is a PHP question,  and any answer (it seems) might reference the language independence as part of the reasoning. I would post these as two separate questions, and if one is answered,  I might reference that answer in an answer to the other (mentioning the language independence of the function as a reason for the other answer being relevant)

Answer (score 9):

In this instance, I think the question should only be tagged [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), since it is about a POSIX function, and would attract more experts in that area. If your programming question has to do about [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), then that tag would be relevant, but in this case it's inappropriate since you are asking about the *general* behavior of the function(s). If your question was asking about the PHP *implementation*, then it would be appropriate. It's not surprising that they behave the same and if they behaved differently, it would either be a bug or should be documented in the PHP manual. The PHP manual's page on [Process Control](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pcntl.php) says:

> This documentation is intended to explain the general usage of each of
>   the Process Control functions. For detailed information about Unix
>   process control you are encouraged to consult your systems
>   documentation including fork(2), waitpid(2) and signal(2) or a
>   comprehensive reference such as Advanced Programming in the UNIX
>   Environment by W. Richard Stevens (Addison-Wesley).

---

Some alternate tags I would suggest are [posix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/posix) or [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) (or [unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unix), it really depends on the context).

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow's functionality is that you can ask for answers and search for one. The search capabilities will work better if you ask one question per post, not two. This way we will read the most valuable information for the question we are looking for. Instead of course when the two topics are almost only existing together, in that case it can be useful.

In your case I would say that asking the same question twice in different languages is fine. As long as it benefits the community.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's okay to group languages of the same family, such as C# and VB.NET, or C and C++, as long the as problem can be reproduced on any of them. You probably should include a code piece in each of the languages mentioned, unless it's actually a carbon copy (C and C++ case).

It's a common practice to mention C# and VB.NET also saying in your question that solution in any of them is acceptable. Make sure to show some research effort, and **always include code if you're tagging with a code tag**. You may even want to translate a part you are struggling with into both languages.

If you need an algorithm and you don't know how to translate it into a language, please have at least some pseudo-code, or steps required to do, and point out the one which you are having trouble with. Stack Overflow is not a code conversion/writing service, so please be as specific as possible about your problem. Include as little information as you can, yet enough to understand and reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I feel it is ok since only the logic remains same. If the person who is asking the doubt is pretty new with that language he would need a clear answer in that language rather than some other language. Mainly those questions related to algorithms and data structures you need to be sure of the language. Also the way of assigning variables and writing functions differ in different languages.